# Login with requests in Python no wrking

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

I tried to login into a website. I have no clue why it doesnt work. To login you need something called 'woocommerce-login-nonce'... I scraped the token(which changes when you refresh the site )via beautifulsoup. This is how the token looks in the html file on the site `<input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-login-nonce" name="woocommerce-login-nonce" value="28a347ad37">`  After I had the token I combined it with username etc. and inserted it with payload. However, I still cant log into the site! Can anyone help ? This is the form data:

```
username: test@gmail.com
password: TestPassword123
woocommerce-login-nonce: 28a347ad37
_wp_http_referer: /my-account/
login: Log in
```

Here is my code:

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source = requests.get("https://sneakerboxtlv.com/my-account/")
src = source.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'lxml')

s =  requests.Session()

payload = {"username": "test@gmail.com","password": "Testpassword123","woocommerce-login-nonce": soup.find("input",{"name":"woocommerce-login-nonce"})['value'],"_wp_http_referer": "/my-account/","login": "Log in"}
visit = s.get('https://sneakerboxtlv.com/my-account/')
login= s.post('https://sneakerboxtlv.com/my-account/', data=payload)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding user-agent and update-insecure-requests to your headers. I think that your payload looks OK.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source = requests.get("https://sneakerboxtlv.com/my-account/")
src = source.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

s =  requests.Session()

payload = {"username": "test@gmail.com","password": "Testpassword123","woocommerce-login-nonce": soup.find("input",{"name":"woocommerce-login-nonce"})['value'],"_wp_http_referer": "/my-account/","login": "Log in"}
headers = {"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36", "upgrade-insecure-requests":"1"}
visit = s.get('https://sneakerboxtlv.com/my-account/')
login= s.post('https://sneakerboxtlv.com/my-account/', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

I didn't create an account to test it, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: sry for the late response, I added the headers but when I print the content after doing the post request I cant find the logout button so it might still not work